# algorithm:finding a shortest path through multiple point

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to solve a problem using A* algorithm.
Let me explain the problem :
Let `S` be a starting point and `V = {v_1, ... v_n}` be a collection of points. What we have to find is finding a shortest path starting from S passing through every points in V. (Revisiting is allowed, and points are in Euclidean plane)

To use A*, I defined some member variables to points :

Goal : finding a shortest distance of a path starting from S passing through every points in V

`u.f` := estimated shortest path length passing point u to goal
`u.g` := shortest distance from starting point to point u until now
`u.h` := heuristic distance from u to achieve goal

And define a heuristic function `h(node)` as :

h(node) := minimum manhattan distance from node to passing through point in V or subset of V

Using A*, put starting point to priority queue `q` after initializing g = 0, f = h of starting point.

I'm getting trouble finding a criterion for updating point.

For example, A* algorithm for single starting point and single destination, we update a point as follows :

```
if (point.g + distance(point, neighbor) < neighbor.g) {
    ....
     // update g,f,h of neighbor
    ....

}
```

However with same code above the A* algorithm does not work well(does not get optimal solution).

How can I solve this problem with A* algorithm?

Comment: I'm not sure you _can_ solve this problem using A*, since you'd need a heuristic for the total remaining distance, which is the travelling salesman problem. You might try using A* to calculate the shortest route between each _pair_ of points in V, and then use brute force to see which order of points leads to the shortest overall route?

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't realize I was finding fast algorithm to NP hard problem. Thanks for stopping me from this unsolvable problem.